# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow OnTaskChange Event for existing tasks

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

I am creating custom workflows in SharePoint 2010 using visual studio. Can someone please let me know how can a wait on a task (item) that is already created/existed in the task list or custom list? For my workflow users might have created some tasks, if they did I need to wait on those to be "completed".

Thanks a lot for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Wait for field change in current item" action.